# Combining numbers in the most efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, combinations

I'm looking into a way to combine a data-set with numbers in such a way that the total number of combinations is minimized. The constrain is that the sum of every combination need to be smaller than a certain number.

An example of the problem could look like this:

> **Data-set**: `[11, 10, 19, 2, 12]`
>
> **Constrain**: Sum of combination `=< 21` and every number can only used once.
>
> Manually you can find that the most optimal combination is: `[11, 10], [19, 2], [12]`
>
> **Goal**: Minimize number of combinations

However for large data-sets it is not possible to do by hand.

I have looked among other things into the possibility to use, permutations and linear systems of equations, but to be honest, I don't really have an idea how to solve the problem. Could somebody provide me with some ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Are there any additional constraint? What makes the manual combination you propose better than e.g. `[11, 10], [12, 2], [19]`? Should the order be kept the same? Are more than 2 items allowed in the sub-lists?

Comment: The problem in full generality can be solved with [**linear programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) techniques, but their efficient implementation is all but trivial.

Answer (score 1):

In absence of further clarification, the following algorithm produces the expected output:

```py
def split_max(items, max_sum):
    result = []
    partial = []
    for item in items:
        if sum(partial) < max_sum:
            partial.append(item)
        else:
            result.append(partial)
            partial = [item]
    if partial:
        result.append(partial)
    return result


split_max([11, 10, 19, 2, 12], 21)
# [[11, 10], [19, 2], [12]]
```

(note that this does not necessarily produce the minimum number of sub-lists if it is allowed for the items to appear in different order).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to `itertools.combinations`

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> myList = [11,10,19,2,12]
>>> [i for i in combinations(myList, 2) if sum(i) <= 21] # first will be your iterable, second is the position here you need combination for 2 position
[(11, 10), (11, 2), (10, 2), (19, 2), (2, 12)]
>>>
```

Comment: There is more to it in the question.